# What are the best practices approaches for forecasting responses with multiple regression Timeseries models?

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, forecasting, modeling

I am building a multiple regression time series model, in the response(y) depends on the relative amounts of two independent variables (x1,x2). However, both of the independent variables (x1,x2) are actually partially dependent on a third variable (z). Z is most likely to be influenced by business cycles or to have some seasonal repetitiveness (z is most likely to have a signal).
So the response can be thought of as having an indirect relationship with variable z.
The end goal of the modeling exercise is to forecast out of sample values of the response variable y.
I am wondering if the following process is a sound method for doing so:
assume I want to forecast out 30 days.
0. Extrapolate a fitted trend-cycle component from z the size of the sample of y.

1. create a regression model for x1 as a function of fitted trend-cycle z and maybe lagged z.
2. create a regression model of x2 as a function of fitted trend-cycle z and maybe lagged z
3. Forecast x1,x2 out 30 days based on its relationship to fitted trend cycle z, save these forecasted values of x1 and x2, as well as their fitted in-sample values.
4. regress y on in-sample fitted values of x1 and x2.
5. Use coefficients from (4) and forecasted values of x1 and x2 to forecast preditions of y for next 30 days.
   Is the above approach reasonable or is there a better best practice approach?

Comment: Do you observe $z$? (Seems unlikely since we rarely get a good contemporaneous business cycle indicator.) Also, have you investigate estimating these jointly?

Comment: Thanks did have an initial model that interacted z with x1 and x2. I believe that z is more likely to have more identifiable patterns then x1 and x2, because of it's scale.